# React Native multiple project dependency in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, dependencies, sendbird

I have an existing React Native project that uses FBLoginManager and AIRMap.  Now I've just git cloned a brand new codebase (smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript), did an npm install to get the needed module.  Yet when I tried to run Xcode on the new project, I got error about 
  "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FBLoginManager.Events')"
and warnings about AIRMap.

The new project has no reference to FBLoginManager or AIRMap. Where is the dependency coming from?

Comment: Okay i found out the problem. I had the packager running for the old project already on localhost:8081.  I killed that and restarted, and no longer see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, need to kill the react native packager that Xcode started for the older project.